# application.properties is not packed in the jar file after copying the ui static resources to src\main\resources\static folder

Tags: angular, spring-boot, microservices

In pom.xml file

```
<resources>
    <resource>
        <directory>target/frontend</directory>
        <targetPath>static</targetPath>
    </resource>
</resources>
```

(I need to copy the output of angular2 to the static folder)
And the application.properties is not packed in the generated JAR file T.T

It works ok if I remove the above  tag.

Do you have any idea on this case?

=========
SOLVED: Still dunno why, and I solved my problem as following:

```
    <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>target/frontend</directory>
            <targetPath>static</targetPath>
        </resource>
        <resource>
            <directory>resources</directory>
            <includes>
                <include>**/*.yaml</include>
            </includes>
        </resource>
    </resources>
```

Comment: What if you add another `<resource>` section besides the front-end, and [include](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/examples/include-exclude.html) your `application.properties`?

Comment: Thanks @Morfic, I solved my problem in the same way as you, and really don't understand why this kind of problem happens